# Push my side content up so the empty space is taken up

Tags: html, css

I have a issue with my side content (`recent-news`) and main content (`recent-articles`)
I want the elements to be aligned as seen on this picture: https://prnt.sc/vxvc9w

HTML5 code

```
    <header>
      <a class="logo" href="#"><img src="assets/img/icon.png"></a>
      
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#">Account</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#login">Login</a>
              <a href="#signup">Signup</a>
          </div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Tips</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Partners</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
   </header>

   <div class="container recent-articles">
     Articles about how to help the environment 
    <ul>
      <li class="article">
         <h1>Title of news page</h1>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetodit</p>
         <img src="assets/img/icon.png">
      </li>
      <li class="article">
         <h1>Title of news page</h1>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetodit</p>
         <img src="assets/img/icon.png">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
    
   <aside>
    <div class="container recent-news">
        <ul>
          <li class="article">
            <h1>Title of news page</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetodit</p>
            <img src="assets/img/icon.png">
          </li>
          <li class="article">
            <h1>Title of news page</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetodit</p>
            <img src="assets/img/icon.png">
          </li>
          <li class="article">
            <h1>Title of news page</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetodit</p>
            <img src="assets/img/icon.png">
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </aside>
```

CSS

```
/* Importing fonts */
@font-face {
    font-family: openSansRegular;
    src: url(../assets/font/OpenSansCondensed-Light.woff);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: openSansBold;
    src: url(../assets/font/OpenSansCondensed-Bold.woff);
    font-weight: bold;
}

body {
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
    font-family: openSansRegular;
}

/* Global tags */
.container {
    text-align: center;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

/* Header */
header {
    background-color: #449342;
}

.logo {
    padding: 0%;
}

.logo img {
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 10%;
}

.logo img:hover {
    width: 5%;
}

/* Navigation */
nav {
    background-color: #2EAF7D;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
    margin-bottom: 0%;
}

nav ul li {
    margin: 0% 5% 0% 5%;
    display: inline;

}

nav ul li a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

/* Nav dropdown */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

/* Recent articles */
.recent-articles {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: green;
    width: 50%;
}

.recent-articles ul {
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}

/* News content */
.recent-news {
    background-color: #449342;
    width: 30%;
    float: right;
}

.recent-news ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0%;
}

.article {
    border-bottom: solid black 1px;
}

/* Article Title */
.article h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
}

/* Article body paragraph */
.article p {
    font-size: 16px;
}

/* Article Image */
.article img {
    width: 10%;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated please.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure from your description that this is what you are asking for, but to get two elements beside each other, either you need to float them left/right, or make them inline: i.e. they can not be unfloated blocks.

I see you float the elements inside the `<aside>`, but that will do just that, float it inside the `<aside>`. Not float the parent element. You need to work with the, in this case, "wrapper" for the sidebar which is `<aside>`.

So, with that said, the quick fix would be to add this to your css:

```css
aside{
    display: inline;
}
```